# Conditional sum in MongoDB

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, mongodb-query

here is the Mysql Query:

```
SELECT name, sum(case when reason = 'fb' then score else 0 end) as fb, sum(case when reason = 'email' then score else 0 end) as email from multi_group group by name
```

I am trying to convert this query in MongoDb:

```
$query = Model::raw(function($collection) {
            return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$group' => [
                    '_id' => [
                        'name'=>'$name',
                        'fb'=> [ 
                            
                            '$cond'=> [
                                [ '$eq'=> ['$reason', 'fb']], 
                                '$score', 
                                0
                            ]
                        ],
        
                    ]
                ],
            ]]);
        });
```

any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: so did the answer below worked what you got, I am interested to know as I have not tested it myself

Answer (score 1):

It is not tested though but I believe this should be ok.

```
$query = Model::raw(function($collection) {
            return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$group' => [
                    '_id' => [
                        'name'=>'$name',
                        ]
                    'fb' => ['$sum' =>
                        [ 
                            '$cond'=> [
                                [ '$eq'=> ['$reason', "fb"]], 
                                '$score', 
                                0
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'email'=> [ '$sum' =>
                        [
                        '$cond'=> [
                            [ '$eq'=> ['$reason', "email"]], 
                            '$score', 
                            0
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            ]);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

i just changed 0 to 1 and it worked

```
$query = Model::raw(function($collection) {
        return $collection->aggregate([
        [
            '$group' => [
                '_id' => [
                    'name'=>'$name',
                    ]
                'fb' => ['$sum' =>
                    [ 
                        '$cond'=> [
                            [ '$eq'=> ['$reason', "fb"]], 
                            '$score', 
                            1
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'email'=> [ '$sum' =>
                    [
                    '$cond'=> [
                        [ '$eq'=> ['$reason', "email"]], 
                        '$score', 
                        1
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        ]);
    });
```